# Bounded Linear operator on a Hilbert space with orthonormal basis

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space with $\{e_n\}$ an orthonormal basis. Then, which is false for $T:H\to H$:

a)$T(e_n)\neq e_1\forall n$

b)$T(e_n)=e_{n+1}\forall n$

c)$T(e_n)=\sqrt{\frac{n+1}{n}e_n}\forall n$

d)$T(e_n)=e_{n-1}\forall n$

I think a) is false, because  the linear operator can just map any element of the basis to any other element? Am I right in that? What about other options. Thanks beforehand.

Comment: Is the question which of these operators are linear and bounded? Or what else do you mean by "false"?

Comment: @Frederikv.E.I mean whether the operator defined by the given options is false

Comment: An operator is not a statement so it can't be "true" or "false". One however can check if the operator is *well-defined*, *linear* and/or *bounded*. I think what @rapidracim said in the comment further below holds here: "I think your problem lacks of information and/or clarity."

Answer (score 1):

consider the space of square-summable sequences $ℓ^2 = \{ (u_n)_{n\geq 1} \subset \mathbb{C}, \; \sum_{n \geq 1}|u_n|^2 < \infty \}$

it is a Hilbert space with respect to the inner product $(u_n,v_n) = \sum_{n \geq 1} u_n \overline{v_n}$ and it's got an orthonormal sequence $\{e_n\}$ defined as follows : $$e_n = (0,0,0, \cdots,1,0,0,\cdots,0,\cdots)$$

the $1$ is in the $n$-th slot

consider the operator

$\begin{align}A_n : &ℓ^2 \to ℓ^2 \\
 &e_k \mapsto e_1 \text{ if } k = n, 0 \text{ if } k \neq n\end{align}$

if $X = (X_1,X_2,\cdots,X_n,\cdots) \in ℓ^2$ then clearly $A_nX = X_ne_1 = (X_n,0,0,\cdots,0,\cdots)$

$A_n$ is obviously linear.

also $\| A_nX \|^2 = \| X_ne_1 \|^2 = \sum_{n \geq 1}|X_ne_1|^2 = |X_n|^2 \leq \|X\|^2$

this proves the boundness.

and it's easy to notice that $A_ne_n = e_1$

a) is false then

Comment: thanks, what about other options?

Comment: @vidyarthi you could always construct a bounded operator which makes the other options false. I think your problem lacks of information and/or clarity.